# How to get the unique identifier of an application on IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uniqueidentifier

I would like to get the unique identifier of my application that is used as the file name in the IOS file system. How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about path to your app which contains uniq. identificator then you can extract this id from path of main bundle `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]`.